# Flume - How to tail many files in a directory without knowing their names?

Tags: logging, chef-infra, flume

I have a directory where there are many files generated with unique but random names.

```
chef-{32_digit_id}
chef-http-{32_digit_id}
```

The id's are unique. I need a way to tell Flume to tail these files by giving a wildcard character like

```
chef-http-*
```

I've been trying this out but Flume doesn't pick it up. The command looks something like this:

```
tail -F /var/log/logpath/chef-http-*
```

But if i give a single absolute path of a file, it works! but not when i use a wilcard character.

It reports

```
ERROR! failed to parse data
```

I'm trying to provision this using chef. If it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use Chef to do a Dir.glob and save that to a node attribute and pass that to Flume?

Comment: What if there are files created every now and then? The chef is provisioned only once in the instance right? (At the beginning). 

If there was a way to do this, then the provisioning needs to happen every time there is a new file(correct me if i'm wrong).

Comment: Depends on how you use Chef. Most people run it as a service. It's not just for provisioning.

Comment: Ok, so we use it only for provisioning new instances with necessary packages and to set up flume etc etc. 

I think this is more of a flume issue.